# Closest distance using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I need a help to solve this:

Find the points on the curve $x^2 + 4y^2 =4$ that are closest and furthest from the points on the curve $C: x^2 +y^2 +4x+2y=20$.

My try:

Let $f(x,y)=d^2(x,y)=(x-t)^2 + (y-s)^2$, with $(t,s) \in C$ and $g(x,y)=x^2 + 4y^2 =4$ restriction. I think something is missing...

Comment: Notice that C is a circle.

Comment: If $(t,s)\in C$, then you have a second constraint of $t^2+s^2+4t+2s=20$.

Comment: If you must do this by Lagrange multipliers, then it's a 4d problem with 2 constraints